# Anyone know of a knot to tie two wires together under strain?

Tags: cables, rope-knots

I'm putting up a wind turbine.  The turbine will be at the top of a 30' 1-1/2" pipe tower.  I have a 30' RV extension cord (10ga/3 conductor) that I'm going to cut the ends off of and use as my down-pipe wiring.  The wind turbine itself has a foot or so of 10ga stranded wire hanging down on the inside of the tube from the bottom of the turbine (three wires).  They say that this wire can support 55# of downtube wiring (total, on the three wires), which is probably right, but I have my doubts that a crimped connector will hold that weight.  The extension cord supposedly weighs 12# at its full 36' length, including the ends I'm going to remove, which are probably a pound of the total.  Full weight of the 30' that will be dangling will be about 10#, but it has to be able to deal with twisting forces a bit too.

So, I know about the underwriter's knot, and how to tie that for three conductors.  But I won't have any kind of stop in the pipe to hold the weight.  The best I can do is tie the two sets of three conductors in a way that the wire is holding the weight, not the connector - like an underwriter's knot does.  But what I'm looking for would be some kind of knot that's like an underwriter's on top of another underwriter's.  Anyone heard of something like that?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using cordage for the down-pipe wiring instead of say UF cable?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't supporting the wire's weight with a strain relief affixed to the supports, rather than expecting the connection to take that strain?

Comment: Let me say it another way. It would never be recommended to support a long cable drop from its connections. In this case the down travel electrical cable should be supported and strain relieved at several places along its length.

Comment: Also, your turbine is too short to be 7200 watts, why the 10 AWG cable and what voltage is this? There are common but fatal errors made in the area of power transmission from small turbines, you may want to discuss it.

Comment: Let's do those one at a time.  @ThreePhaseEel, Cordage instead of UF - is there a reason I'd use UF instead of an extension cord?  The manual says a suitable extension cord is what's usually used.

Comment: @keshlam - Why not a strain relief?  No place to attach it, not called for in the manual.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, Except that's what's recommended in this manual.

Comment: @Harper, my turbine is too short for 7200 watts - Well, it's 400 watts.  Why the 10AWG?  Because I did a voltage drop calculation for the whole run, and decided 10 AWG provided a reasonable drop.  Here's the turbine:http://www.homedepot.com/p/Nature-Power-400-Watt-Wind-Turbine-Power-Generator-for-12-Volt-Systems-70500/203916953

Comment: BTW, what I did was an underwriter's knot, with the conductors of my downpipe cable passing through the loops, and all ends traveling back down, with connections then made about 6" below the knot, and several cable ties holding all of those down-pipe cables against the main cable going down.  All strain is on the cables, not on the bondage.  I'll be taking it down for service this summer, so any *useful* suggestions for a good strain relief would be appreciated.

Comment: @user3224303 Please see [Rule 1](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @user3224303 It is not clear to me from your comment if you have any physical load on the knot, but if you have then you should endeavour not to. Please see the post by jgrady at [Underwriters Knot](http://www.antiqueradios.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=36679) which starts "Bringing up the ole electrician stuff, UL knots make for a great short circuit/explosion."

Comment: @Tester101 - is there some way to respond to your comment somewhere else?  It's troubling that so many of those comments pretty clearly violated rule #1, but you decided to admonish me for it.  Looks like this part of stackexchange has lots of problems with people not knowing they're being rude. Harper's first comment still falls under that category.  I'd never tell someone "So your whole concept is right out." to their face unless it was a friend.

Comment: @user3224303 You can discuss this more in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement).  Remember, rudeness is subjective, so it isn't always so black and white.  If you find any comments rude, you should flag them for moderator attention, or link to them in chat.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - The really odd thing is that the manuals for these turbines clearly say to just crimp the connectors on to the wires, and as long as you're under 55#, that's good enough.  Clearly it isn't, and my idea to use an underwriter's and put the strain on wires not connectors is better, but still, that strain relief below is the answer.  As to eventual fires, this is a farm.  The mice will be a problem *long* before that.  Still, I'll put a strain relief in when I figure out how to get it in there. Thx.

Comment: @user3224303 You could attach the electrical cable to some thin flexible stainless steel rope (at multiple points) and then you only have to worry about attaching the steel rope to take the strain. You might even have some around already on a farm.

Comment: I should explain what the connections look like a bit more, because while I absolutely have wire rope, there's no place to attach it.  What you get is 1-1/2" pipe, flared at some ends so that the pipe connects together.  It's not particularly thick pipe, so any holes you make it in are going to structurally eventually be problems.  The turbine fits over the top-most pipe, and makes no holes in the pipe to attach (basically clamps on).

Comment: The wires come out of the inner part of the turbine base, where there's a solid molded plastic disk, with the wires spaced out through the disk.  If you're willing to risk destroying that plastic disk, you might be able to screw something into it, but you have no way of knowing how thick it is, or what's above it, except that the equally spaced wires come down through it.

Comment: Finally, back to the pipe - except for a single bolt hole in the bottom, that connects the bottom pipe to the base, there are no holes in the pipe (except down the middle, of course).  Guy wires are attached to rings that slide down on the outside of the pipe.  The pipes are subject to weather, vibration, and flexing.  So drilling holes in them (thin galvanized) would probably cause fairly rapid failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this [Cable support wedge](http://catalog.pecoelect.com/viewitems/rigid-conduit-fittings-steel/cable-support-wedges)

[image: Cable support wedge]

NEC 300-19 specifies when to use them, in this case if the cable is under 100' none are needed.

Looking at the manual for the next larger wind turbine, it very specifically says to use standard sleeve wire crimps to connect the wiring coming out of the turbine to the down-tube wiring.  These support wedges would clearly be better than that.  They're wood.  You set your wire into one or more of the openings (anyone have experience with these who can tell us how to size them? The 'wire fill' part isn't clear), and drive the wedge into the tube.  The wood compresses going into your pipe/conduit, and compresses onto your cable in the process, holding it in place.

Hope that helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 2):

The strain relief being referred to in comments:

[image]

You'll probably need to visit an electrical supply store in your area to pick one up, I've never seen them in a big box store.

Comment: The top three are for pulling.  And yes, you need to shop at a real electrical supply not a big box store.

Comment: What I'm looking for, and no one seems to have come up with yet, would be a strain relief that internally wedges into the pipe.  So, look up 'star fangled nut' as one idea.  I've never seen such a thing for a strain relief.  I've seen service entrance connectors that use a rubber compression seal, but I've never seen anything that clamps outward on the inside of a pipe, leaves room for a cable to pass through, then seals onto the cable to hold it.